# Element custom properties not being kept after loop

Tags: javascript

I have some more complex code with a strange behaviour that I've managed to reproduce here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <div>things</div>
    <div>stuff</div>
    <div>other</div>
    <div>misc</div>
    <script>
        var forEach = function (array, callback, scope) {
            for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                callback.call(scope, array[i], i);
            }
        }
        var d = document.querySelectorAll('div');
        d[1].o = d[1].textContent;
        forEach(d, function (el, i) {
            d[1].innerHTML += '<p>div things</p> sdf d';
            document.body.innerHTML += '<div>new div</div> fdsffsd fsdf';
            alert(d[1].o);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I should get 4 alerts, each saying "stuff". And I do, until I do a hard refresh, and then a normal refresh. Then only the first alert says "stuff", and the others say "undefined". It appears the "o" property being added to `div[1]` is not being kept. It seems to be related to the `innerHTML` being added to the `body` in the loop. The `innerHTML` being added to the `div` doesn't seem problematic.

I cannot see what the problem is. Moreover, this only seems to happen in Chrome (v43) and not in Firefox.

Any ideas?

Comment: I just tested, I get the alert 4 times (with a refresh and hard refresh) all saying "stuff" using Chrome! I suspect you have other code on the page, which is causing the issue? Works in IE 11 too, and FireFox (dev edition)

Comment: Your code is `d[1]` each time ... did you mean to use `d[i]`?

Comment: I did mean d[1]; that's the test whether the property is kept or not. Thanks for giving it a go, I'll try in a fresh browser install.

Comment: I think I just figured it out. In the actual code I'm using, the properties I'm setting contain quite a lot of text. Most contain HTML tags, and that seems to be the problem.

Comment: Can you update Chrome... Version 34 is I think quite 'old' ~(I think April 2014)... Why are you using such an old version?

Comment: Oops, that was a typo. I meant 43.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is happening when the body's innerHTML is updated is that the whole of the body's innerHTML needs to be reparsed. This means any custom properties attached to any elements are then lost, as these DOM elements are being recreated.

Thus one should probably not be using innerHTML with the += operator unless you're sure you know what you're doing.

Why it even worked sometimes is a mystery...